# Hide Drupal Primary Menu Items Before Login

Tags: php, drupal

I created a site using drupal 6.I want to show primary menu items only for logged in user.If user is not logged in,i want to hide all primary menu links.How can i do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primary menu can be printed in two methods in themes:

1. if primary menu is shown via block, then check visibility settings for that block for authentificated roles, except anonymous;
2. directly printing in page.tpl.php, then use next code:

   ```
   <?php 
     global $user; 
     if (isset($primary_links) && $user->uid) {
       print theme('links', $primary_links, array('class' => 'links primary-links'));
     }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Printing in page.tpl.php cab be different, investigate your page.tpl.php first.

Comment: Hi Nikit..i didnt find any such ines in pages.tpl.I am using zend theme.But i found that we can do it using admin configuration wizard.It comes under SiteBuilding->Block->PrimaryLinks